# Equations for outputs of nodes in hidden and output layers of a Neural Network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Hey guys, I'm new to neural networks.. I want to know how to come up with equations for outputs of nodes in the hidden and output layers of a neural network.  I would like to know the answer to the below and how you did it.  I haven't been able to find any approchable reading material on this either.

Assume I have a binary classification problem.  Assume that I have a multi-layer neural network with one hidden layer.  Assume that I have a sigmoid activation function given by `f(x)=1/(1+e^-z)`.  Does anyone know how I find the equation for the output of the nodes in the hidden layer and the output of the nodes in the output layer?

Thanks guys, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I reduced a three-layer NN to a set of equations (1 input node, 3 hidden nodes, 1 output node), and I ended up with those shown in the image.  (Note: I'm assuming the image upload worked - they are blocked by company's morality filter).

1. I labeled the output of each node as
   *o*, subscripted as {layer,neuron}.
2. The weights were labeled as *w* with
   subscripts indicating
   {to_layer,neuron} and superscripts
   indicating {from_layer,neuron}.
3. The bias terms *b* were subscripted as {layer, neuron}

As shown, the scaled NN input (*Cet*) was formulated as the output of the node on layer 1 (labeled as Eqn 3 in the pic).  My sigmoidal activation function resembled yours (Eqn 4).  From there, the output of layer 2, node 1 was computed (Eqn 5), then output of layer 2, node 2 (Eqn 6), then output of layer 2, node 3 (Eqn 7).

The output (*BISt* in my pic) was then computed as the weighted sum of the hidden layer activations - which was then passed through the activation function.

[image: equation fig]

This strategy worked well for my application.

Comment: Thanks.. I will read over this carefully later and press accepted answer when I've had time to understand :).

Comment: No problem - let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: in case of that sigmoid function rather than -x why is there 0.8*x in equation 4 can you please explain me that

Comment: @ashim888 Specifics: the publisher dropped the "-" in the exponent.  It should be exp(-0.8x). 
General statement: the 0.8 factor serves as a "shaping" term that effectively controls the steepness of the squashing function around x=0.  Higher values (i.e. 10 in this case) increase the steepness and cause the squashing function to head toward a unit step function.  Lower values (i.e. 0.1 in this case) decrease the steepness and cause the squashing function to more resemble a line near x=0.